# Error trying to rebase msys-2.0.dll:

Tags: windows, git, cygwin

Using Cygwin on Windows 7 64 bit.

Trying to rebase  `msys-2.0.dll`: for Git with the below command.
However I am getting the message saying its skipped because its wrong machine type.

```
cd  /cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/Git/bin

$ rebase.exe -b 0x50000000 /cygdrive/c/"Program Files (x86)"/Git/bin/msys-2.0.dll

 /cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/Git/bin/msys-2.0.dll: skipped because wrong machine type.
```

What does this mean? Trying to look up on Google but didn't find much information anywhere - so hoping someone in this community can help.

Answer (score 0):

As [mentioned here](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-gnu-emacs/2014-09/msg00867.html), it could be a Cygwin issue depending on your current version of Cygwin.

But you can also try the alternative *without* cygwin, using the [latest git-for-windows](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases):

- unzip [`PortableGit-2.6.3-64-bit.7z.exe`](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/download/v2.6.3.windows.1/PortableGit-2.6.3-64-bit.7z.exe) anywhere you want
- add to your `%PATH%` the folders `C:\path\to\PortableGit-2.6.3-64-bit\bin` and `C:\path\to\PortableGit-2.6.3-64-bit\usr\bin` (that last path comes with 200+ Linux gnu commands: `ls`, `xargs`, `awk`,... all accessible from your `CMD.exe` session!)

Then try again your git commands.